# How do I set trigger to copy user_id to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I need a trigger in phpmyadmin for 2 tables.

I have two tables called `users` and `group_has_users`. Table `group_has_users` has 2 values called `group_id` and `user_id`.

I'm trying to make a trigger that automatically inserts new data to `group_has_users` table with `user_id` when new user is created in `users` table( with `group_id` set to `1`)

How to do this with phpmyadmin trigger?

```
insert into group_has_users (user_id) values (new.user_id);
```

I have no clue to make it group_id to set `1`.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: insert into group_has_users
 (user_id)
 values
 (new.user_id); Ihave no clue to make it group_id to set 1

Comment: Please don't post code in comments!  Always post it in your question and make sure you indent it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
delimiter $$

create trigger after_insert_users
after insert on users 
for each row begin

if new.group_id = 1 then

insert into group_new_users (user_id) values (new.user_id);

end if;

end $$
delimiter ;
```

Note that you will have to run this in your cli or in [mysql workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime a new record is created in table `users`, you are looking to automatically create a new record in `group_has_users`, with a default `group_id` of `1`.

Consider the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER users_after_insert
AFTER INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO group_has_users(group_id, user_id) VALUES(1, NEW.user_id);
END;
//
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rsJZbKAngyr43vZJDyPXha/1)**:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TABLE users (user_id int)//   
CREATE TABLE group_has_users (group_id int, user_id int)//

CREATE TRIGGER users_after_insert
AFTER INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO group_has_users(group_id, user_id) VALUES(1, NEW.user_id);
END;
//

INSERT INTO users(user_id) values(1);

SELECT * FROM group_has_users;

| group_id | user_id |
| -------- | ------- |
| 1        | 1       |
```